# Implementing JS fuzzy search in Sinatra (ruby)

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, haml, fuzzy-search

I am trying to use [fuse.js](http://kiro.me/projects/fuse.html) for *fuzzy search* in a [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) project but I am a bit lost with JavaScript implementation.

I have created `route` with all my data in `JSON` format:

```
# encoding: utf-8
class Lambree < Sinatra::Base
  get "/json/all" do
    content_type :json
    @pre = Prescriptions.all
    @pre.to_json
  end
end
```

Then I loaded `fuse.js` and added a function in my `layout.haml`:

```
:javascript
  $(function() {
    $( "#fuse" ).search( {
      onSelect: function(text) {
          var data = $.getJSON("/json/all")
          var f = new Fuse(data);
          var result = f.search('Falen');
        }
      }
    );
  });


%label{:for => "search"} Ψάξε:
%input#search/
%button#but{:onclick => "search()"} Search
```

This of course, doesn't work.

I need to understand how to call JS functions, because I'm missing a lot but can't say exactly where to start! Any example with some code and step by step explanation would be more than welcomed!

Thanks

Comment: `$.getJSON("/json/all")` - just remove proto/domain.

Comment: Thanks I added edited the post and adjusted the code with your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Now answering real question. You need to pass search text to your ruby code.

```
$("#fuse").search({
  onSelect: function(text) {
    var data = $.getJSON("/json/all", {text: text})
    var f = new Fuse(data);
    var result = f.search('Falen');
  }
});
```

After that get it in your method (I don't remember how to use sinatra, sorry, following code may or may not work as is).

```
get "/json/all" do
  content_type :json
  text = params[:text]
  pre = Prescriptions.find(name: text)
  pre.to_json
end
```

And you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your time! When I call the JS function `$("#fuse").search(...);` Safari (debugger) comes up with an error `TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$( "#fuse" ).search')`. See here http://atmosx.clarify-it.com/d/lwlk4a

Comment: `$` and `getJSON` tells me that it requires jQuery.

Comment: JQuery is loaded and fuse.js is loaded too. Weird. I will check it out again, ty.

Comment: There are two versions of JQuery loaded: 2.1.1 and 1.10.2 . First required by google fonts second required by `datepicker`.

Comment: If I remove the `$` from `("#fuse") ...` seems to work fine. Query wasn't needed my bad. However, now the views can't seem to find `onclick='search()'` function.